# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/Environment"

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, capacitor

Trying to set up Firebase Authentication based on [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication).

However, I'm getting an error related with pods:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/Environment":
  In Podfile:
    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (~> 8.2.0) was resolved to 8.2.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAuth (~> 8.2.0) was resolved to 8.2.0, which depends on
          GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.4)

    CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
      GoogleUtilities (~> 7.2.2) was resolved to 7.2.2, which depends on
        GoogleUtilities/Environment (= 7.2.2)
```

**What I tried already:**

- `pod install --repo-update`
- `pod repo update`
- `pod update`
- increase `platform :ios` version
- add `pod 'Firebase/Auth'` to `target 'App' do` in Podfile

It seams that if I downgrade `cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication` to `v4.0.2` than it works but I don't know how sustainable it will be moving forward.

Comment: Do you have other firebase plugins installed? Looks like some of them require different versions of dependencies

Comment: @jcesarmobile no, but I do have `cordova-plugin-googleplus` and `@ionic-native/google-plus` for signing in with Google.

Comment: Yeah, it’s cordova-plugin-googleplus what requires GoogleUtilities ~> 7.2.2, report an issue on their github repository

Comment: @jcesarmobile you're right. That was it! For a quick fix, there is an updated fork available at https://github.com/gitstc/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Comment: thanks, after pod downgrade and removing the google analytics plugin is working fine